# can we measure resource usage by a task under sleep in linux/VxWorks?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, operating-system, rtos

I have encountered sleep routines in VxWorks RTOS and POSIX thread(on Linux ).
Once I started with micro controller programming I came across
situations   where the tasks which are going to sleep will be run by a slower clock,
 i.e clock   switching happens before putting a task in to sleep.
From this I am getting the Idea that a sleeping task is still using the clock   cycles and memory.Taking the same concept to the VxWroks/Linux Scenarios,
Is   there any method by which we can actually check/profile  the resource/cycle usage  by sleeping tasks/threads?.
Any technique related to VxWorks or Linux  would help much

Comment: For non-trivial preemptive multitasking OS, the cycles used during sleep() is zero.  Some will be used during the call and return operations but, otherwise, sleeping threads are not given execution at all - they specifically requested to not receive any for some interval, so they get none.

Comment: As for memory, the thread stack, data, code may well be paged out, as requested/demanded by other threads/processes.